# TTFB of > 30secs on only one page of website

Tags: wordpress, amazon-ec2, pagespeed

All of the pages on my website are loading within 2-4 secs with the exception of one page (the login page).

For some reason the TTFB is aprox 30 secs.

It is a WordPress site hosted on an AWS EC2 micro instance with Cloudfront CDN.

When I check the pages on pingdom they average 2-4 secs with the exception of this page:

[Problem page](http://wp360.com/my-account)

Is there any way of working out why it is so slow and  fixing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running it through Pingdom shows that it's waiting 30s for a server response, so you need to start looking at your DB queries. I'd recommend two plugins for this: [Query Monitor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/) and [Debug Bar](https://wordpress.org/plugins/debug-bar/). If you install these, they will reveal which particular queries are taking a long time to execute. Once you know what you're looking for, you can then start to figure out how to alleviate your problems.